# Silverstripe: get var from many_many relation custom upload

Tags: silverstripe, relation

I would like to know how customize this uploadfield to get from $belongs_many_many Act table.

A part of the code....

```
<? 

class MultipleBlock extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Act' => 'Varchar',


    private static $many_many = array(
        'MultipleBlockColumns' => 'MultipleBlockColumn'
    );


}

class MultipleBlockColumn extends DataObject {

    static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'MultipleBlocks' => 'MultipleBlock'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
    );

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Image',$uploadField = new UploadField(
                $name = 'Image',
                $title = 'Image'
            )    
        );

    enter code here
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Uploads/Subsite'.Subsite::currentSubsiteID().'/images/'.$var);

}
```

I have tried these methods to get Act variable but nothing appear:

```
$var=$this->Parent->MultipleBlocks->Act;
$var=$this->many_many(MultipleBlocks)->Act;
$var=$this->Parent->Act;
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... after some days, and learning Silverstripe little more, I have found my solution. To achieve MultiBlocks from MultiBlock column is this :

```
parent::MultipleBlocks();
```

To make my save to folder customization, there is my code... It works perfectly well. The ID of the MultiBlockColumns must be create first.

```
$parent = parent::MultipleBlocks();
            $uploadField->setFolderName('Uploads/Subsite'.Subsite::currentSubsiteID().'/images/'.$parent['MultipleBlock']->Act);
```

That's it! Thanks for submitting idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, the reason why you aren't able to access the `Act` variable is due to the fact that you're not iterating through the `MultipleBlocks` relation. A sample of how to get the `Act` variable for a the related `MultipleBlocks` would be as follows (within your template/layout file):

```
<% loop $MultipleBlocks %>
$Act
<% end_loop %>
```

In php it would be something along the lines of:

```
$multipleBlocks = $this->MultipleBlocks();
foreach($multipleBlocks as $block){
    $act = $block->Act;
}
```

When you reference `MultipleBlocks` as you did in the `$this->MultipleBlocks->Act` it won't work as `MultipleBlocks` is a many relation so it's actually a `DataList` rather than an individual object.

Update

Here is the has_many/has_one example:

```
class MultipleBlock extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Act' => 'Varchar',
    );


    private static $has_many = array(
        'MultipleBlockColumns' => 'MultipleBlockColumn'
    );


}

class MultipleBlockColumn extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'MultipleBlock' => 'MultipleBlock'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
    );

    public function getBlockAct(){
        return $this->MultipleBlock()->Act;
    }

}
```

Comment: The php example only shows how to loop through the blocks and access the `Act` variable. It doesn't handle anything to render it in the template/layout.

Comment: If I understand... It's not possible to do this. But, If relation was has many and has one,, do you think that I will be able to get the table variable Act with $this->MultipleBlocksID->Act ? Not getting variable for templates but customization for a upload field.

Comment: If your MultipleBlock has_many MultipleBlockColumns and the has_one going the other way then you could do `$yourMultipleBlockColumns-> MultipleBlockRelationName()->Act` to get that variable. I've updated my above answer to show how this would be done more completely.