# Silverstripe accessing has_many data from a separate page type

Tags: php, mysql, has-many, silverstripe, has-one

I'd like to start by saying that I'm new to Silver Stripe development and PHP/MySQL in general, so please be kind.

I have a site that requires me to have a pricing page that displays the company's pricing plans on both the pricing page (duh) and the homepage. So, the goal is to be able to access the data from my `Pricing.php` page type with my `HomePage.ss`.

I'm trying to make this as future proof as possible so I've created a `ServicePlan.php` that extends DataObject and uses a `FieldList` to create the pricing records and associate them with the `Pricing` page type via a `$has_many` and `$has_one` relationship. Based on my limited knowledge this seems like the best way to accomplish this.

Here's the code that I've written to accomplish this.

**ServicePlan.php**

```
class ServicePlan extends DataObject {

private static $db = array (
    'PlanColor' => 'Varchar',
    'PlanName' => 'Varchar',
    'PlanPrice' => 'Varchar',
    'PlanRenewal' => 'Varchar',
);

private static $has_one = array (
    'Pricing' => 'Pricing'
);
private static $summary_fields = array (
    'PlanName' => 'Name of Plan',
    'PlanPrice' => 'Price',
    'PlanRenewal' => 'Renewal Period',
);
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('PlanName'),
        TextField::create('PlanRenewal'),
        TextField::create('PlanPrice'),
        TextField::create('PlanColor')
    );
    return $fields;
}

public function getServicePlans() {
    return $this->Pricing();
}
```

**Pricing.php**

```
class Pricing extends Page {
private static $has_many = array (
    'ServicePlans' => 'ServicePlan',
);

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();


    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Plans', GridField::create(
        'ServicePlans',
        'Orenda Force Service Plan Information',
        $this->ServicePlans(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ));

    return $fields;
    }
}

class Pricing_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

**HomePage.php**

```
class HomePage extends Page {
}

class HomePage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    public function ServiceTeasers($count = 2) {
        $holder = ServicesHolder::get()->First();
        return ($holder) ? ServicesPage::get()->limit($count) : false;
    }

    public function MembershipPlans() {
        $Pricing = Pricing::get();
        return $plan;
    }
}
```

**Layout/HomePage.ss**

```
...//

<% loop $MembershipPlans %>
    <div class="col-1-3 card pricing">
        <div class="pricing__header  primary $PlanColor">
            <p class="pricing__plan-name">$PlanName</p>
            <p class="pricing__price">$PlanPrice<sub>$PlanRenewal</sub></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__contents">
            <h3 class="title-06">Plan details</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>unlimited training</li>
                <li>individual nutrition/meal plans</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    $Content
<% end_loop %>

...//
```

I'm having no issues accessing the content

**Layout/Pricing.ss**

```
<section class="body pricing">
    <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title-02 text-monochrome">Pricing</h2>
        <% loop $ServicePlans %>
            <div class="col-1-3 card pricing">
                <div class="pricing__header $PlanColor">
                    <p class="pricing__plan-name">$PlanName</p>
                    <p class="pricing__price">$PlanPrice<sub>$PlanRenewal</sub></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__contents">
                    <h3 class="title-06">Plan details</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>unlimited training</li>
                        <li>individual nutrition/meal plans</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end_loop %>
    </div>
</section>
```

I really appreciate any help that you all can provide, I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days and I've been hitting a brick wall time and time again. What am I doing wrong?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475944/silverstripe-get-var-from-many-many-relation-custom-upload) is the closest I've gotten and it didn't seem to solve my issue. Should I move the `FieldList` to the `Pricing.php` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for your home page you have most of what you need already. You're just missing the loop for the `has_many` that the Price page has. Since your `MembershipPlans()` function in the `HomePage_Controller` returns all of the price pages as a `DataList` you can access the related objects by looping through the relation name, in this case `<% loop $ServicePlans %>`.

**HomePage.ss**

```
<% loop $MembershipPlans %><!-- loop Price pages -->
<% loop $ServicePlans %><!-- this is your loop for the ServicePlans related to the particular Price page -->
<div class="col-1-3 card pricing">
    <div class="pricing__header  primary $PlanColor">
        <p class="pricing__plan-name">$PlanName</p>
        <p class="pricing__price">$PlanPrice<sub>$PlanRenewal</sub></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card__contents">
        <h3 class="title-06">Plan details</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>unlimited training</li>
            <li>individual nutrition/meal plans</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<% end_loop %><!-- end ServicePlans relation loop -->
$Content<!-- Content for particular Price page -->
<% end_loop %><!-- end Price pages loop -->
```

Comment: @user4765523 BOOM! you should mark the answer as correct to make this solved!